# White opacity box in html and adjusting title (photoshopped) picture

Tags: html, css

I need help with making a white opacitz window on which i can write text...
And if its possible to help me position the title picture so i could look better and not squeezed.

```css
text-align: center;
}


body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: normal;
 background-image: url("https://www.jamesallenonf1.com/wp-content/uploads/Screen-Shot-2017-08-01-at-12.00.11.png");
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
*
{
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto; 
}

#header {
 position:relative;
 width: initial;
 height:99px;
 margin-left:29px;
 margin-right:21px;
    text-align: center;
}




.title
{
position:relative;
left:30px;
top:22px;
text-align:center;
font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size:40px;
font-weight:bold;
color:red;
}

.articleTitle
{
text-align: center;
padding-left:25px;
padding-top:10px;
padding-bottom:10px;
color: #000;
font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:24px;
font-weight:bold;
}

.articleContent
{
width:auto;
position:relative;
padding-left:25px;
padding-right:25px;
color:#000;
text-align:center;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
line-height:25px;
}


#bar
{
 list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: red;
    position: sticky;

}

.menuLink
{
 height:36px;
 width: 130px;
 text-align:center;
 float:left;
 font-family:Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size:15px;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#000;
 padding-top:20px;
}

.menuLink:hover
{
 background-color: white; 
 
}
a
{
text-decoration:none;
color:#000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>F1-Info</title>
 <style>
 body {

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
     <div  class="title"><img width="1000px" height="120px" src="f1Domo.png"></div>
       
    </div>
    <div id="bar">
        <div class="menuLink"><a href="index.html">Home</a></div>
        <div class="menuLink"><a href="index.html">About</a></div>
        <div class="menuLink"><a href="index.html">Portfolio</a></div>
        <div class="menuLink"><a href="index.html">Services</a></div>
        <div class="menuLink"><a href="index.html">Contact</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="pageContent">
    
    <div class="articleTitle">F1-Info</div>
        
        
      <div class="articleContent">
      
      
             <br> <br> <br>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Integer mi. Vivamus sit amet neque vitae sapien bibendum sodales. Curabitur elementum. Duis imperdiet. Donec eleifend porttitor sapien. Praesent leo. Quisque auctor velit sed tellus. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean laoreet imperdiet nunc. Donec commodo suscipit dolor. Aenean nibh. Sed id odio. Aliquam lobortis risus ut felis. Sed vehicula pellentesque quam.</p><br />
          <p>Vestibulum augue hroifhreoghrehgoirehgirfiorwiof wh uwrhiu wiu uiw uwuifwoi guiwoiwui goiw guhi fwuisgviwrhug ui vuwrhkswoig jklwv wj jwbvui nkjvw wfjw bjkvwn wkj wv hwv jw hjwnwibv kwjoiwh woiv hw oiw jw wbquam, interdum id, congue semper, convallis non, velit. Quisque augue tortor, tristique ac, scelerisque eget, aliquam id, sem. Aenean lorem. Fusce velit nibh, dapibus quis, laoreet nec, porta a, dui. Nullam ac urna. Proin eget elit. Nunc scelerisque venenatis urna. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce congue, turpis ut commodo mattis, pede erat fringilla tellus, pulvinar suscipit odio lorem sed pede.</p>
 </div>


    </div>
        
</body>
</html>
```

[Here is the sreenshot of my webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiYiW.jpg)

And I need help with adjusting the title picture.

Comment: can explain further what you're trying to do, and point the elements in your code so we can help

Comment: well first i need an white window with opacity of 0.5 in which i can write text beacuse i have a very dark background picture

Comment: Assuming the articleContent box is what you are trying to add a transparent white background to. Just add a background color with an alpha channel (ex: background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5)) to the articleContent.

Answer (score 0):

Use rgba color for background. For white its:

```
#YOURDIV {background: rgba(256,256,256,0.5);}
```

You can google it to find more info. Example: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space

As for understand and use the background images: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly , and assuming that you want to make it the `articlecontent`

try this  in your css file

```
 div .articleContent {
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    }
```